# Iterating level by level in python

Tags: python, loops

For a section of my programming assignment I want to do the following.
In the level 1 I have an input number (N) which I'm dividing by another number(X).In the next level same input number (N) is divided by X*2. Likewise I want to go on calculating until the final result becomes less than or equal to 1.

For instance if X=8 and N=2 in first run I will divide 8/2=4
In the next run I will divide 8/4 which is 2
In the last run I will divide 8/8 which is 1

I'm trying to implement this in python. I have the basic idea of the code as follows:

```
    def myFunc(n, x):

         first_level=n/ x 
         next_level = n /x * 2
         ............

         if result <=1:
             break

    myFunc(8, 2)
```

But I don't understand how to iterate calculating the possible next levels. Please help.

Comment: Create a loop. Each time, you're dividing `n` by `(x*i)`, where `i` starts as `1`, etc. Add your condition to exit the loop.

Comment: After 1st level,  using while loop keep divide by x*2 with condition result larger than 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive function: Added the print to show that the result is equal to 1.

```
def myFunc(n, x):

    result=n/ x 
    if result <=1:
        print result
    else:
        myFunc(n,x*2)

myFunc(8, 2)
```

Or to get the levels you can use a global variable:

```
count = 1
def myFunc(n, x):
    global count
    count = count + 1
    result=n/ x 


    if result <=1:
        print result
    else:
        myFunc(n,x*2)
myFunc(8, 2)
print count
```

Comment: Recursion isn't necessary for this, and should generally be avoided because of the overhead it incurs. IMO, a simple loop would be better.

Comment: Thanks a lot for introducing global variables. It makes easier to capture the number of levels.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample function that does this via iterating!

The key here is to set a temporary variable which keeps track of the current value of the loop, thus allowing you to make the division.

```
def myFunc(n, x):

    i = 1
    interim_result = n

    while interim_result > 1:
        interim_result = n / float(x**i) # I guess you're working with integers, but just in case
        print "This is loop number: " + str(i) + " with result: " + str(interim_result)

        i = i + 1

myFunc(8, 2)
```

Hope this is clear.

Comment: Yes this is very clear. I got the idea of adding the interim_result. Thanks a lot.